# Besides welding, are there other ways to connect this gear to its axle?

Tags: repair, washing-machine, welding

This is washing machine's agitator axle and a gear from transmission. The weld that connected them both had failed.

[image]
**Since I don't have welder at my disposal, I am wondering, if besides welding there are other ways to connect this axle and gear back together?**

As one example, I have a tap and die set and was thinking that I could drill a hole in the axle and gear. Put a bolt. And then file the bolt's head smooth? Though, I am wondering what could happen in the worst case if bolt fails (e.g. stall motor, cause belt to fail)? Any other ideas?

Comment: If you use a bolt, how will you stop the gear rotating - the constant vibration will cause it to loosen...

Comment: How about dipping the bolt in JB weld before screwing it in? Though, I don’t have any idea what loads there are and if this will hold. Maybe just better to properly metal weld this

Comment: How about taking it to a local welding shop and have them weld it for you?

Comment: Another possibility would be to drill a hole perpendicular to the long axis of the shaft through both the shaft and the gear and tap in a pin.  In this case I'd add some "red" threadlocker to keep it in there permanently.

Comment: Is the shaft round or does it have a flat? If the shaft is round I doubt a pin will hold for long washing machines have a large torque to get the clothes moving , a pin would have been much cheaper and probably easier to assemble, the MFG is not using a pin because it won’t last, drill out enough for a bolt and the shaft will break, I would really only consider welding if a round shaft I can’t quite tell.

Comment: You can use a car battery and jumper cables, and buy just an electrode.  Now you have an Arc Welder capable of tacking something on.